# Detect close event of JavaScript in below code

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, window

I am trying out this example of Flex-JavaScript communication.

But I am not able to achieve it. Please could someone help me out ?

Here's my code :
**main.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;
            private function callJavaScriptFunction():void {
                if(ExternalInterface.available)
                {
                    ExternalInterface.call("myBasicFunction");
                }
                else
                {
                    Alert.show("ExternalInterface unavailable");
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button label="click" click="callJavaScriptFunction()" x="200" y="200"/>
</mx:Application>
```

and JavaScript function that I wrote in `index.template.html` under `html-template` directory of the project.

```
 <script>

var win;

function myBasicFunction() {
    win = window.open('','','width=400,height=300');
    win.onbeforeunload=onUnloadHandler;
}

function onUnloadHandler()
{  
  alert("window closed");
 }
</script>
```

---

```
<mx:Label id="lbl" useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" text="Google" selectable="true" mouseChildren="false" mouseEnabled="true"
              mouseOver="{lbl.setStyle('textDecoration','underline'),lbl.setStyle('color','#0000FF')}" 
              mouseOut="{lbl.setStyle('textDecoration','none'),lbl.setStyle('color','#000000')}" 
              click="navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://www.google.com'),'_blank')"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

You can check for an open window with a timer call to `checkOpen`

```
var win;
function myBasicFunction() {
  win = window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
}

function checkOpen () {
  if (win.closed == true) {
    alert("Window closed");
  } else {
    alert("window still open");
  }
}
```

Or you can add an unload event handler on the opened document and within the unload event handler call a function on the parent window using `window.opener.closedHandler()`.

Code of your main window

```
function myBasicFunction() {
    window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
}

function myWindowClosedHandler() {
    // code here
}
```

Code of your opened window may look like

```
<body unload="onUnloadHandler">

<script>
    function onUnloadHandler()
    {  
        window.opener.myWindowClosedHandler();
    }
</script>
```